# In Emacs why can I not paste text C-y into a C-s search box?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs why can I not paste text C-y into a C-s search box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Follow this pattern:**

1. Esc-W       // To copy of the selected text into buffer
2. Ctrl-s Then press return.
3. Ctrl-y Then press return.  // To paste selected text

Then repeat Ctrl-s for incremental search. Similarly for decremental search, use Ctrl-r.

Comment: Small correction: Esc-W is actually M-w (where Meta can be done with pressing ESC *followed* by the command key, or by pressing Alt *together* with the command key; all depending on configuration (and keyboard, if you happen to have a Meta key ;-)))

Comment: Interesting trick, didn't know about pressing return when in i-search :·)

Comment: I'd underline the fact it is needed to press RET just after `C-s`. I missed it, and wondered why the paste didn't worked.

Answer (score 6):

The command you are looking for is `isearch-yank-kill` which is bound to <kbd>M-y</kbd> when in isearch

> M-y runs the command
>   isearch-yank-kill, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `isearch.el'.
>
> (isearch-yank-kill)
>
> Pull string from kill ring into search
>   string.

Answer (score 0):

Since Emacs 24.1, you can.

> C-y in Isearch is now bound to `isearch-yank-kill`, instead of
>   `isearch-yank-line`.

(from http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.24.1)